# mocha test the promise, catch exception case

Tags: typescript, mocha.js

I have a test :

```
it('should not save a user if it already exists', ()=>{
    var user : User = {userName : 'jack', name : 'Lenon'};
    var user1 : User = {userName : 'jack', name : 'Linon'};
    return repository.saveUser(user)
    .then((user:User)=>{
        return repository.saveUser(user1)
    }).then((user : User)=>{
          expect('Second ').equals('');
        })
        .catch((err) =>{
            expect(err).equals("A user by that username already exist in the database");
        });
});
```

The idea is to test the repository rejecting to save a second user by the same name. This works, but I am not happy at all with the way I force a failure in the "then". Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: Not too familiar with the typescript syntax. But if you're using promises you should probably be using the async mocha test (i.e. accept a 'done' callback). In this case you can call done( new Error( "Test Failed" ) ); to safely fail the test. Alternatively you can throw an error. I usually do this by simply using assert( false ); Not sure how this would work with expect() though.

Comment: @Mitch The OP's test is returning the promise, so there is no need to use the `done` callback. (This, by the way, is completely independent from Typescript. It's just how Mocha works.)

Comment: Wasn't aware that mocha inherently supported promises. You learn something new every day :)

Comment: This is really nice, I like this approach much better than the "done" method. But there is a gottcha : if I forgot to "return", mocha says everything is OK, when the test was actually failing.

Comment: Here's an article I wrote on testing promise failures in mocha http://catfish.life/testing-promises-with-mocha/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Chai.

Then `expect('Second ').equals('');` can become `expect.fail();`

https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_fail

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to assert that the promise is rejected, you can take advantage of the second callback function of `then`. If the success callback is called you should `throw()` because the test should fail. Then in the second callback which should fire if the promise rejects, you can assert the error value. Something like:

```
return repository.saveUser(user)
.then((user:User)=> repository.saveUser(user1))
.then((user : User)=> {
            // test will fail if promise resolves
            throw new Error("Promise should not be fulfilled when user already exists")
       },
       err => {
            // test will pass if promise rejects 
            // and the expectation is met
            expect(err).equals("A user by that username already exist in the database");      
       }
)
```